# joining others minecraft pe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing on an Iphone 6 plus minecraft edition 13.0 alpha. My son is playing on an IPad mini, the same version. We have been unable to join each other's. However my daughthers' all three of them on their indiivdual iPad minis can join each others worlds an their brothers. Am I the odd woman out because I am using a cellphone? Or is their perhaps a step we have missed? Thank you for your help.

Kay B.

Answer (score 0):

No, I have had this problem, and it's very simple to fix. You go and click the create a new world. You click the arrow thing like making a server. Type in your name in the first  column. Then go to your settings and go to wifi. Click on the wifi your attached to. Then look at the IP address. And type the same IP address in the IP address box. Then click create, and they should be able to join you. I would do this with all the devices just incase.